# Where can I find working example project using PMD in Gradle with Java 11?

Tags: gradle, pmd

Where can I find working example project using PMD in Gradle 6.x with Java 11?  Every time I try to get my project working with PMD and Java 11, I always running into errors like this one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.PMDASMClassLoader.getImportedClasses(PMDASMClassLoader.java:107)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.populateClassName(ClassTypeResolver.java:1502)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit(ClassTypeResolver.java:200)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTCompilationUnit.jjtAccept(ASTCompilationUnit.java:41)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.TypeResolutionFacade.initializeWith(TypeResolutionFacade.java:18)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.AbstractJavaHandler$5.start(AbstractJavaHandler.java:104)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.usesTypeResolution(SourceCodeProcessor.java:153)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource(SourceCodeProcessor.java:180)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:96)
```

A working sample project would really help me to debug this issue.

Comment: Please indicate the Gradle and PMD versions you are using. It is quite likely that one of them is not compatible with Java 11.

Comment: I believe it is Gradle 6.1.

Comment: Gradle 6 defaults to PMD 6.20. PMD has supported Java 11 since PMD 6.6.0. Hence, I think you are either using a different Gradle version, or are overriding the PMD version in use. Please, provide your current config to betters asses this.